# how to find margin of error of the interval for the true slope of Up in following senarios?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

An individual 80% interval
Bonferroni correction  and scheffe with a family-wise confidence level of 80%.
I have a data of:

```
______________________________________________________________
|farm      | up             |right           |left           |
| -------- | -------------- | -------------- |-------------- |
| 24.3     | 34.3           | 50             | 45            |
| 30.2     | 35.3           | 54             | 45            |
| 49       | 45             | 540            | 4353          |
| 70       | 60             | 334            | 343           |
| 69       | 80             | 54             | 342           |
```

for "bonferroni" I have used:

```
library(multcomp)
K <- rbind(c(1, -1/2, -1/2), ## idk why and what is the logic
           c(1, -1, 0)) 
plant.data.K <- glht(fit.plant, linfct = mcp(group = K))
summary(data.glht.K, test = adjusted("bonferroni"))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to find margin of error of the interval for the true slope of Up in following senarios?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/552328/how-to-find-margin-of-error-of-the-interval-for-the-true-slope-of-up-in-followin)

Comment: @Pitouille Your research is valuable, so when you discover a duplicate, please vote to close one of the threads.  That will have a more constructive effect than just leaving a comment.

Comment: @whuber, actually I flagged it as duplicate and then the system generated this comment. I am not sure if my profile/experience allows me to vote to close. I will check next time if I can do it. Thanks.

Comment: @Pitouille Thank you for the explanation.  I had forgotten that 3,000 rep was needed to vote to close.  I hope you reach that level soon.  I am grateful for the research and effort that underlie the identification of any potential duplicate post and wish it could be better rewarded.

Comment: @whuber, I am working on it! Thanks for your kind words.